# How to get Frostie the snowman

Tags: samurai-vs-zombies

How do you acquire Frostie the bowman in samurai vs zombies? I really need him because I keep dying.

Comment: Why is this tagged with skyrim?

Comment: Don't know. Fixed it though.

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer posted [here](http://www.mobicheats.com/samurai-vs-zombies-defense-cheats-tips-iphoneandroid/#comment-1799) (bolding my own):

> **The only way to get him is through a blue or a gold present.**...There are some stages that have an abundance of presents (stages 35-40 are recommended)

And some info about Frostie the Bowman from the same reply:

> He doesn’t get affected by riflemen and has half the effect of lethargy with every shot without stack up. He costs twice as much as the standard archer (20 Leadership) and *only targets the front-most targets in a group.*

Just having him in no way guarantees that you will stop dying. In fact according to several posts, Frostie suffers from only being really useful in a limited number of scenarios because of his high cost, slow rate of fire and not receiving an effect from riflemen. His most notable uses as described in various sources online are for stunning flying enemies and against the boss of stage 50.

Comment: @Trent Is there some way that I can improve the answer to this question to better answer your question?